Зависает Apache
В последнее время стал зависать apache. А точнее html страницы грузиться а php вечно грузиться. После перезапуска apache на какое-то n время все хорошо, а потом опять. Менял настройку MaxRequestWorkers и ServerLimit по разному, все равно никак не хочет. Помогите пожалуйста
ERROR LOG APACHE:
[Wed Sep 11 20:34:00.624825 2024] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 586332] AH00161: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting
[Wed Sep 11 20:35:54.929023 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 586332] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Wed Sep 11 20:35:55.113313 2024] [suexec:notice] [pid 604938] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/lib/apache2/suexec)
[Wed Sep 11 20:35:55.354081 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 604939] AH00163: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 mpm-itk/2.4.7-04 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Sep 11 20:35:55.354135 2024] [core:notice] [pid 604939] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Sep 11 20:50:47.495355 2024] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 604939] AH00161: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting
[Wed Sep 11 20:54:10.332370 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 604939] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Wed Sep 11 20:54:10.545226 2024] [suexec:notice] [pid 609836] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/lib/apache2/suexec)
[Wed Sep 11 20:54:10.676930 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 609837] AH00163: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 mpm-itk/2.4.7-04 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Sep 11 20:54:10.676977 2024] [core:notice] [pid 609837] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Sep 11 21:49:11.184310 2024] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 609837] AH00161: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting
